# Overriding a function in classes

Tags: c++, class, overriding

I am confused on how to override functions
if I have

```
class  C
{
  public:
    C ();
};


class A: public C
{
  public:
    virtual string write()=0;
};
```

and I make another class

```
class B: public A
{
    public:
       string B :: write() override {}
};
```

is this not valid for class B inheriting class A virtual method and overriding it?

ok so in main, I am not allowed to call the constructors for this abstract class correct? But if that abstract class has constructor which it inherited how do I call them?

```
void main()
{
   B();
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in the definition of class B

Comment: yes, I meant to put "public A," and I put "class A" by mistake, but that syntax error is not in my code, thanks

Comment: I think you just need to remove the `B::` qualifier

Comment: ok so in main, I am not allowed to call the constructors for this abstract class correct? But if that abstract class has constructor which it inherited how do I call them?

Comment: the whole idea with an abstract class is that it is... abstract. if you call B() you are in effect attempting to create an object where the method  write() is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for inheriting from another class, should be something like this:

```
class B: public A{
   public:
      virtual string write(){
        //do something
        return someString;
      }
};
```

Comment: but what about overriding the method so the inherited class is not abstract?

Comment: ok so in main, I am not allowed to call the constructors for this abstract class correct? But if that abstract class has constructor which it inherited how do I call them?

Comment: Which constructor do you want to call? The constructor of `class C`?

Comment: yes from Class C, this is the main problem because in my main, it is not allowing me to construct the objects because and its saying that one of the objects is a pure virtual function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify `override` (available in *C++11*) here, you can do it like this.

Header file

```
class B : public A {
 public:
  virtual string Write() override;
}
```

CPP file

```
string B::Write() {
// Your implementation here.
}
```

In fact, it's a good practice to specify `override` when that is your actual intent. It avoids error such as trying to override `string A::Write()` with `string B::Write() const`, but get the result of defining a second function. In this case, if you specify `string B::Write() const override`, it will be a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

> is this not valid for class B inheriting class A virtual method and overriding it?

You need to drop the redundant (and illegal) `B::` and return something. Otherwise it's fine.

> I am not allowed to call the constructors for this abstract class correct? But if that abstract class has constructor which it inherited how do I call them?

You can't call constructors directly at all; that's not how the language works. Constructors are called indirectly when you create an object:

```
B b;  // Create an instance of B, indirectly calling B::B(), which calls A::A()
```

Since `A` is abstract, you can't create an object of that type; only of derived types like `B` which override all the pure virtual functions.

Comment: But if the derived class (B) is derived from an abstract class (A), and the abstract class is derived from a regular class(C), how do I in main call the contructors in C, from B, because it should have inherited the contructor from C right?

Comment: @user2521432: You don't call the constructor. It's called automatically when you create an object. `B` has an implicit constructor, which calls the (implicit) constructor of `A`, which calls the constructor of `C`. So creating an object of type `B` will correctly initialise its `C` sub-object with its constructor.